# How do I make dailaog box rounded rectangular in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

In my app a dialog box automatically captures a screen as a full rectangular area.

I want to change to rounded rectangular. Can I change the dialog box in `theme.res` in Codename One? Or do i need to write any code to change the dialog box to rounded rectangular?

I used Dialog.show() method but when i change dialog as a rounded rectangular from theme.res. so it shows changes in theme which i used but in my application their is no required change is apply. It appear same as a previous.

so tell me their is any issue or what can i do for apply changes on my all dialog?

Answer (score 1):

The `Dialog` UIID covers the entire `Form` due to the way dialogs are implemented (they are technically regular forms that cover everything).

We have the following builtin UIID's you can use:

- `DialogBody`
- `DialogTitle`
- `DialogContentPane`

If you just set the other two to have no border the `DialogContentPane` should work but won't include the title since that's outside of the content pane area. I would suggest defining the `hideEmptyTitleBool` theme constant to true in that case.

Our builtin Android/iOS dialogs are rounded and we used 9-piece borders to do that. We cut out the border for the `DialogTitle` which is rounded on top and square below and we cut out a border for `DialogContentPane` which is the mirror of that (rounded below and square on top). So they fit together perfectly.

Ideally we'll revisit this styling in the future as we try to make styling easier. All of this was done before our newer rounded border implementations existed and during the iOS 4.x period where the iOS `Dialog` design was more complicated.